# How can i write the code which support all languages(specialcharacters)

Tags: utf-8

I create one webpage with create page html.

I have created event as **早上好** in **chinese**. But it is showing the event  as **æ©ä¸å¥½**.

What would be the problem here.and tell how to resolve this. please explain me.

I am already adding this code in my html file,

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

But it cannot show as the event name like as I have entered.

Comment: Ooookayyyy...!? The answer is: you need to handle encodings correctly for the technology you're using. Obviously we have no idea what that technology is or what exactly you're doing or not doing or doing wrong!

Comment: this article could help you [Displaying Chinese Characters in HTML](http://www.inventpartners.com/chinese-chars)

Comment: Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` in beginning of the page that will make the page HTML5 and compatible with your code..